# Insecure content images and js over ssl using htaccess

Tags: php, security, .htaccess, ssl

I have the following htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !ssl

....// lots of rewrite rules

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteCond $1 !^ssl
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteCond $1 ^ssl
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Basically when I load a secure page I get lots of insecure images and js being loaded
how can I modify my htacccess to get this content loading securely.

Note that the folder for the images and js are

```
/js 
/images
```

and secure content is served from /ssl

Thanks

Comment: A user can still MITM content that is being redirected.  This is still vulnerable to attack,  you should use the "security" tag to get a real answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent redirect, for the images and js folder, by putting this at the top of your htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(js|images)/ - [L]
```

Also make sure you only use relative or root-relative (or protocol-relative) urls for referencing images and javascript files.

Comment: -1 this does not prevent attack.  The system is still vulnerable.

Comment: @Rook. Please explain. As long as relative urls are used, the images and js are requested using https if the current page is using https. Since the RewriteRules Dino created force https for urls starting with `/ssl/`, the images and js is also indirectly force to use https.

Comment: @Gerben an attacker is going to MITM the request,  you're server will never have the opportunity to issue a redirect.

Comment: @Rook but that is an inherent problem with the internet, and there is no real solution to this problem beside `Strict-Transport-Security` header, which only works on repeated visits. So unless you want to `-1` every answer on SO about https...

Comment: @Gerben: there is one solution: make sure all the content embedded on a page served over HTTPS use `https` links.

Comment: @Rook. Huh? If you use relative url on a https page the referred media is retrieved using https too. No need to specifically add `https://` in front of every link. Also a MITM attack can still occur if the visitor first uses http to visit the page, and no redirect to the https version has occured yet.

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your header section

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

This meta tag will automatically upgrade all http requests to https request. However your images must be available in https, otherwise, it will not be shown (ignored). This is the fastest way to fix mixed-content in secured pages.

Comment: Not 100% sure this was what worked, but it's a good suggestion.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

when you're browsing a secure web page that contains non-secure content like this case(e.g image), browsers **DO NOT** send referrer header,So there is no server side solution to find out this is requested from secure web page or not?
you have to use relative path for those files to served securely!